# Windows XP File Sharing force asking for credentials

Tags: windows-xp, file-sharing, credentials

I want to know how to setup my share so it will always ask for credentials. So I don't have to map a drive on every computer I go to and then delete it so the user doesn't have access to my share folder after I leave. This is in a windows xpsp3 environment.

Answer (score 1):

Passwords - you should use them